# how to draw animated level bar in TVirtualStringTree?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I am targeting to draw a custom animated progress bar in `VST`

My goal is drawing a similar result as image below, I tried to do something like this `OnBeforeCellPaint`:

```
procedure TForm2.VTs1BeforeCellPaint(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex;
  CellPaintMode: TVTCellPaintMode; CellRect: TRect; var ContentRect: TRect);
var
  NewRect : TRect;
  xOff, yOff : Integer;
  ProgressBarRect: TRect;
  Percents: Real;
  DrawProgressBar: Boolean;
begin
  //draw progress
  Percents := 10; // 40%
  // progressBar on Column 3
  begin
  // draw progressbar
    ProgressBarRect.Left := 0;
    ProgressBarRect.Top := CellRect.Top + 1;
    ProgressBarRect.Right := round((CellRect.Right - CellRect.Left) * Percents)  + CellRect.Left;
    ProgressBarRect.Bottom := CellRect.Bottom - 1;
    if (ProgressBarRect.Right - ProgressBarRect.Left) > 0 then
    begin
      TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := RGB(179,255,102);
      TargetCanvas.FillRect(ProgressBarRect);
    end;
  // ProgressBarRect
    inc(ProgressBarRect.Left);
    inc(ProgressBarRect.Top);
    dec(ProgressBarRect.Right);
    dec(ProgressBarRect.Bottom);
    if (ProgressBarRect.Right - ProgressBarRect.Left) > 0 then
    begin
      TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := RGB(221,255,187);
      TargetCanvas.FillRect(ProgressBarRect);
    end;
  end; 
end;
```

but I can't do the same result and reach the same approach as the image which follows:

[image]

That's the result I've got in coding:

[image]

The progress bars are coming along to the node not beside it and its not same design as showing in the image it comes yellow long back ground of the node I wanted to make it in the left side of the node and have the same design of the animated image that I've posted above.

Comment: *"but i cant do the same result and reach the same approach of the image"* Why not? what is different, what doesn't work and in what way?

Comment: added result image in question

Comment: This is before cell paint, so the actual cell paint may overwrite what you are doing. So, do you not need to modify the var ContentRect?

Comment: i create new rect to show the progress bar beside that left of the node name also the design comes out one shape not like the image at all. i am trying to do same result of the animated gif image

Comment: But your rect width is a percentage of cell width. Surely it should be a percentage cell height, and a fixed width?

Comment: percent it to allow the VSt on validate to animate the rect it could be 40 / 10 / 20 , or i am doing all wrong

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with the added image! Where is the VST? Where is the drawn progressbar? Please, try to formulate your problem verbally as good as you can, until then I must downvote, because your question is unclear.

Comment: i mean the animated image that i posted in the question . the drawn progressbar is the yellow one in the second image of VST

Comment: @TomBrunberg Question edited with more details

Comment: I repeat, you are doing a percentage of the cell WIDTH, not the cell HEIGHT, which is what you need. Also you need to make your cell height bigger.

Comment: @Dsm i dont know how to do this in coding can you answer the question with how to do it right ? i will appreciate it

Comment: my confusion is here  `round((CellRect.Right - CellRect.Left)` should it be from bottom to top ? because i test that and the progress disappear

Comment: See my added answer. Don't forget that x% is really x/100 so that might be why the progress disappears

Comment: I've reverted your edit: the question was answered based on the further details you've provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnBeforeCellPaint` triggers only once, before the cell is painted.

I've used a timer to repaint the VST in order to "animate" the rect.

Notice that `Percents` is a decimal, not a percentage value, so `100%` is `1`.

A very basic demo follows:

```
private
  Percents: Real;

. . .

implementation

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Percents := 0;
  VirtualStringTree1.AddChild(nil);
end;

procedure TForm2.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Percents > 1 then
    Percents := 0
  else
    Percents := Percents + 0.025;

  VirtualStringTree1.Repaint;
end;

procedure TForm2.VirtualStringTree1BeforeCellPaint(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex;
  CellPaintMode: TVTCellPaintMode; CellRect: TRect; var ContentRect: TRect);
const
  CPROGBARWIDTH = 30;//rect width
  CPROGBARSTEPS = 6;//how many rect is 100%
var
  r: TRect;
  h, n: Integer;
begin
  if Percents > 1 then
    Percents := 1
  else if Percents = 0 then
    Exit;//nothing to draw

  h := Round(CellRect.Height / CPROGBARSTEPS) - 1;

  r.Top := CellRect.bottom - h - 1;
  r.Left := 1;{align left}
  //r.Left := CellRect.Right - CPROGBARWIDTH - 1;{align right}
  r.Width := CPROGBARWIDTH;

  TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := clSkyBlue;

  n := Ceil(Percents * CPROGBARSTEPS);//how many rect to draw?

  while n > 0 do begin
    r.Height := h;
    TargetCanvas.FillRect(r);
    Dec(r.Top, 1 + h);
    Dec(n);
  end;
end;
```

---

**August Holidays Bonus**
AKA "*100% non-animated rect on the left side of the animated one*"

This draws something similar to the animated GIF in the question.

Here a nested routine is used.

```
procedure drawProgress(AWidth: Integer; APercent: Real; ASteps: Integer; ALeft: Integer = 1);
```

`AWidth` the rectangle width
`APercent` the progress percentage
`ASteps` number of chunks which make the full 100% progress
`ALeft` horizontal coordinate of the upper-left corner point of the rectangle

```
procedure TForm2.VirtualStringTree1BeforeCellPaint(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex;
  CellPaintMode: TVTCellPaintMode; CellRect: TRect; var ContentRect: TRect);

  procedure drawProgress(AWidth: Integer; APercent: Real; ASteps: Integer; ALeft: Integer = 1);
  var
    r: TRect;
    h, n: Integer;
  begin
    if APercent > 1 then
      APercent := 1
    else if APercent = 0 then
      Exit;//nothing to draw

    h := Round(CellRect.Height / ASteps) - 1;

    r.Top := CellRect.bottom - h - 1;
    r.Left := ALeft;
    r.Width := AWidth;

    TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := clSkyBlue;

    n := Ceil(APercent * ASteps);//how many rect to draw?

    while n > 0 do begin
      r.Height := h;
      TargetCanvas.FillRect(r);
      Dec(r.Top, 1 + h);
      Dec(n);
    end;
  end;

begin
  drawProgress(10,        1, 7);
  drawProgress(30, Percents, 7, 1 + 10 + 1);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make your cell (row) height bigger. I assume you know how to do that.

Next, as I said in my comments you are using the wrong direction for calculations:

Finally you do not divide your percentage by 100 as you should!

```
procedure TForm2.VTs1BeforeCellPaint(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex;
  CellPaintMode: TVTCellPaintMode; CellRect: TRect; var ContentRect: TRect);
var
  NewRect : TRect;
  xOff, yOff : Integer;
  ProgressBarRect: TRect;
  Percents: Real;
  DrawProgressBar: Boolean;
begin
  //draw progress
  // Percents := 10; // 40% // for testing?
  // progressBar on Column 3
  begin
  // draw progressbar
    ProgressBarRect.Left := 0;
    ProgressBarRect.Top := round((CellRect.Top - CellRect.Bottom) * Percents/100)  + CellRect.Bottom;
    ProgressBarRect.Right := 30;
    ProgressBarRect.Bottom := CellRect.Bottom - 1;
    if (ProgressBarRect.Top - ProgressBarRect.Bottom) > 0 then
    begin
      TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := RGB(179,255,102);
      TargetCanvas.FillRect(ProgressBarRect);
    end;
  // ProgressBarRect
    inc(ProgressBarRect.Left);
    inc(ProgressBarRect.Top);
    dec(ProgressBarRect.Right);
    dec(ProgressBarRect.Bottom);
    if (ProgressBarRect.Top - ProgressBarRect.Bottom) > 0 then
    begin
      TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := RGB(221,255,187);
      TargetCanvas.FillRect(ProgressBarRect);
    end;
  end; 
end;
```

## Edit Note

updated to remove test line that fixes size at 10%

Comment: I assumed this was just for test. You need to remove the line Percents := 10. Will edit.

Comment: How do you animate? I assume refresh via timer?

Comment: invalidate via timer yes same as the  answer below if Percents > 1 then
` begin
    Percents := 0;
 end
  else
  begin
    Percents := Percents + 0.025;
  end; Vts1.Invalidate;`

Comment: For mine I was assuming % 1-100. Did you remove the /100 from the round calculation?

Comment: (To use as is you would need percents := percents + 25)

Comment: i do it +25 result showing as blink bar not liek level bar its like one clolor that refreshed

Comment: Your algorithm did not show level bars, and never did (not even horizontally). That would require you to draw several rectangles (you only draw one). But I am sure that now your fundamental problem is solved, you can handle that yourself. If not, then you should ask a separate question. If it is flashing and you don't like that, that is because of how repaint works and is again a separate question.